# YAML mapping values are not allowed

Tags: yaml

I have the following data. Which is not valid in YAML. Double quotes are not working here:

```
data:"{\gateway\: \172.16.16.1/24\ \modulesModel\: [\N9K-X9364v\ \N9K-vSUP\]}"
```

Is there any better way to format it?

Answer (score 0):

You are starting escape sequences with the backslash.

Use `\\` to represent the backslash in a yaml string.

However your string looks like JSON where `"` are replaced with `\` and `,` are missing completely. Maybe somebody told you to Escape the `"` with `\`. This is done this way:

```
data: "{\"gateway\": \"172.16.16.1/24\", \"modulesModel\": [\"N9K-X9364v\" \"N9K-vSUP\"]}"
```